# Is there a library or typeclass for getting the transformer version of a monad?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

In my current project I've run into the need to turn various monads into their transformer counterparts e.g.

```
stateT :: Monad m => State s a -> StateT s m a
stateT stf = StateT $ return . runState stf
```

It's trivial to write these utility functions for the monads I need, but I was wondering if there already exists a library that contains this functionality for the standard monads and maybe a typeclass that abstracts this sort of transformation. Something like

```
class (Monad f, MonadTrans t) => LiftTrans f t | f -> t where
    liftT :: Monad m => f a -> t m a
```

("lift" is probably the wrong term to use here, but I wasn't sure what else to call it.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out function `hoist` from the [mmorph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) package.

Its signature is

```
hoist :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

Meaning that it can change the base monad underlying a transformer.

Now, in the `trasformers` package, many "basic" monads are implemented as transformers applied to the `Identity` monad, like this:

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

Therefore, we can define the following function (taken form the [Generalizing base monads](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#g:4) section of the `mmorph` documentation):

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

generalize :: (Monad m) => Identity a -> m a
generalize m = return (runIdentity m)
```

and combine it with hoist:

```
hoist generalize :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => t Identity b -> t m b
```

This method won't work for simple monads which are not defined as transformers applied to `Identity`, like the `Maybe` and `Either` monads. You are stuck with [hoistMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-1.4.3/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:hoistMaybe) and [hoistEither](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#v:hoistEither) for these.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to go the wrong way.  If something is a transformer, than the plain version of it is the transformer applied to the Identity monad.  (They are not always implemented like that directly, but should be equivalent modulo bottom.)  But, not all monads are transformers (They need to be universally left or universally right adjoint in order to transform.  [citation needed])

hoist and friends are super helpful, too, but I think it best to invert your process.