# Lift to fix the *inside* of a monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, lifting

Suppose I have an `IO Int` wrapped in a `StateT MyState`, then I have a value of `State MyState Int` which I want to use in the stacked monad. How do I lift it in this inner sense? I already know to use `lift` or `liftIO` if I get something compatible with the inside that I just need to lift to the outside monad, but now I have the opposite problem: the value is already in the outer monad but not the inner one.

For instance:

```
checkSame :: State MyState a -> IO a -> StateT MyState IO Bool
checkSame sim real = do
  rres <- liftIO real
  sres <- ??? sim 
  return $ rres == sres
```

Do I have to 'get' the state, shove it through runState by hand and box it all up again, or is there some generic way to do this?

BTW, that sim parameter is a whole bunch of stateful functions that have nothing to do with IO, so I'm a bit reluctant to make them all return `StateT MyState IO a` if I can avoid it.

Comment: You are correct in wanting to keep the types precise. You can use `mapStateT (return . runIdentity)` or, more generally, `hoist (return . runIdentity)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066858/is-there-a-library-or-typeclass-for-getting-the-transformer-version-of-a-monad

Comment: Note that `mmorph` has the `generalize` function now: `generalize = return . runIdentity`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Find a monad morphism. This is often a matter of finding the right library; in this case [hoist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) and [generalize](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:generalize) together should get you where you need to go.
2. Make your `State` action more polymorphic. This is the commonly used one, and the recommended one; it amounts to pre-applying the morphism from part 1, but has a lot of machinery put in place already in the `mtl` library to make it easy. The idea here is that if you write your `State` action just in terms of `get`, `put`, and `modify`, then instead of the type `State s a`, you can give it the type:

   ```
   MonadState s m => m a
   ```

   Then later, at the call site, you can choose whatever monad is appropriate for this, including both `State s a` and `StateT s IO a`. Moreover, since it specializes to the type `State s a`, you can be sure it doesn't do any `IO` or anything like that that `State s a` itself couldn't do, so you get the same behavioral guarantees.

Comment: I commented on this as an answer below in order to accommodate code.

Comment: Regarding the second option: it pays to be aware that different instances of `MonadState` have different strictness properties.