# Add a monad to the middle of a transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to "semilift" an `(ExceptT Error IO Foo)` to an `(ExceptT Error (StateT Bar IO) Baz)`.

I've tried `lift`, `fmap lift`, and `fmap return`, and none work; is there a standard idiom here?

```
> import Control.Monad.Except
> import Control.Monad.State
> data Error
> data Foo
> data Bar
> data Baz
> x = undefined :: ExceptT Error IO Foo
> y = undefined :: (ExceptT Error (StateT Bar IO) Baz) -> a

> f = ??? -- This is what I'm trying to find.

> :t y (f x)
y (f x) :: a
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [`mapExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:mapExceptT), but your concrete example is difficult to follow.

Comment: See also point (2) at [Lift to fix the inside of a monad transformer stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27206159/791604). Perhaps this question is a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the `ExceptT` newtypes, you have

```
IO (Either Error Foo)
```

And you want

```
StateT Bar IO (Either Error Foo)
```

(I don't see what you want with `Baz`, so I'm ignoring it.)

That is just `lift`. So I believe you should be able to use

```
ExceptT . lift . runExceptT
```

As [Alec noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786924/add-a-monad-to-the-middle-of-a-transformer-stack/45787019#comment78531702_45786924), this can be written using [`mapExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:mapExceptT):

```
mapExceptT lift
```